# Text representation using TFIDF .toarray() freezes my computer. Too many features to handle?

Tags: python, feature-selection, numpy

I'm new to Data Science, so hopefully this question makes sense.

I have a dataset with ~50,000 rows. It consists of one column that has item category in it and one column with item description in it.

I'm trying to get bigrams from the item description with the highest correlation to each category.

i'm using TfidfVectorizer to do this.

I compress the item descriptions into an array using this:

```
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.ItemDescription).toarray()
```

In Spyder, when i even click on the features under variable explorer, the memory immediately shoots up to 99% and my computer freezes.

If I try to call features at all, it will also freeze.

Here is how i'm calling features later in my code after making it into an array:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import numpy as np
N = 2
for UNSPSC, category_id in sorted(category_to_id.items()):
  features_chi2 = chi2(features, labels == category_id)
```

The array size is 50000X12000

Is that too big? Is there anything I can do to get the bigrams without my computer freezing? As a last resort, I will trim down my data. But i feel like that will reduce the accuracy of any model i try to train later.

Please let me know if you need full code.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your downstream algorithm can work with sparse matrices, you can proceed with sparse matrix rather than using toarray.
2. Alternatively, try to minimize the number of features which are created. Check documentation of TfidfVectorizer (parameters like min_df, max_df, stopwords) to filter out un-important words.

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved.

I think the issue has to do with Spyder and not Python itself.

I ran the script using the terminal directly and was able to process. Although it does take a large amount of memory, but it still allows me to function (sub-par) on my computer.

Comment: For the record, that matrix in dense format is a little bit above 2 GB. Try to make use of the fact the return is a sparse matrix, it saves a lot of space.

Comment: Can you please direct me to some reading material?